# How to stop a function after some work to run?

Tags: swift

I have 2 class that they have a shred class like this:

```
class MyClassA {
    
    static let shared: MyClassA = MyClassA()
    
    var hasValue2: Bool = Bool()
    
    func work2(value: Bool) {
        hasValue2 = value
        print(value)
    }
    
}

class MyClassB {
    static let shared: MyClassB = MyClassB()
    
    private let array: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    
    func work1() {
        
        for item in array {
            if (item == 2) {
                MyClassA.shared.work2(value: true)
                break
            }
        }
        
        
        // I need stop function if I already send true value to MyClassA.shared.work2(value: true), if not i need to run next line of code.
        
        MyClassA.shared.work2(value: false)
        
    }
    
}
```

the use case would be like this:

```
func startWork() {
    MyClassB.shared.work1()
}
```

I want function work1 stop sending false value if the function already sent true value otherwise the function can send false value if it did not set true value.

The problem is that the function send true and false value all together, which is not what I want, the function should send true or false and quit the work.

Comment: Instead of `break` use `return` the whole thing will end there. but you can use `async awaits `Task` to `cancel()`

Comment: _function work1 stop sending false value if the function already sent true_, this can be solved by using return as mentioned in the above comment. _otherwise the function..._, "otherwise" will never happened since your code is synchronous, the for loop will always iterate until item == 2 and then return. This also applies to the last paragraph, there is no _or_ here

Answer (score 0):

as [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum) said, instead of `break` use `return` the whole function will end there
but also you can use this code instead of `for`:

```
let doesArrayContainValue = array.reduce(false) { $0 || ($1 == 2) }
MyClassA.shared.work2(value: doesArrayContainValue)
```

this code is searching for value of 2. if array contains this value, than variable will be true. otherwise variable will be false

so now your function will be like this:

```
func work1() {
    let doesArrayContainValue = array.reduce(false) { $0 || ($1 == 2) }
    MyClassA.shared.work2(value: doesArrayContainValue)
}
```

you can read more about reduce function [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/reduce(_:_:))

Comment: I thought about using reduce or filter, but that means you will always traverse the entire array, even if the first item containing a value of 2 is near the beginning. If the array is large and the value==2 occurs near the beginning, it would be slower.

Comment: Semi-related, but you should replace `array.reduce(false) { $0 || ($1 == 2) }` with `array.contains(2)`. That has the benefit of being both simpler _and_ faster (it finishes early once a match is found)

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really make sense. Your code is single-threaded/synchronous code. There's no concurrency.

With synchronous code, there is only ever one thing happening at a time. Your `MyClassB.work1()` function runs beginning to end.

If you just want to skip the final call to `MyClassA.shared.work2(value: false)` if you ever called it with `value:true` from inside the loop, just change your `break` to a `return`, as mentioned in Lorem Ipsum's comment:

```
func work1() {
    
    for item in array {
        if (item == 2) {
            MyClassA.shared.work2(value: true)
            return // <-- Change this line
        }
    }
    
    
    // I need stop function if I already send true value to MyClassA.shared.work2(value: true), if not i need to run next line of code.
    
    MyClassA.shared.work2(value: false)
    
}
```

Comment: Why you said: "Your question doesn't really make sense.", which part has no sense?

Comment: I guess it's the way your phrased it. It made it sound like you wanted to be able to tell your function to stop running from the outside. You want it to terminate as soon as it finds a true value, and not send both a true and a false response. I added code showing how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way I found:

```
 class MyClassB {
    static let shared: MyClassB = MyClassB()
    
    private let array: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    
    func work1() {
        
        var valueToSend: Bool = false
        
        for item in array {
            if (item == 2) {
                valueToSend = true
                break
            }
        }

        MyClassA.shared.work2(value: valueToSend)
        
    }
    
}
```